# MySQL MAX function for categories without using GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I'm having a lot of trouble to figure out how to write the right code in MySQL.

Here is what I have so far...

```
SELECT ProjectSteps.ProjectID, ProjectSteps.StepID, Step.StepName, Step.Definition 
FROM ProjectSteps, Step 
WHERE ProjectSteps.ProjectID = 
    (SELECT MAX(ProjectSteps.StepID) OVER ProjectSteps.ProjectID 
     FROM ProjectSteps 
     WHERE ProjectSteps.ProjectID IN (1, 2, 3) 
     )
ORDER BY ProjectSteps.ProjectID;
```

For my query, I have 2 tables

`STEP (StepId, StepName, Definition)`

and

```
ProjectSteps (StepID, ProjectId, StartingDate, EndingDate)
```

I have to get both the names of the step and of the step definition of the last step I have for every project.

As:

```
Project ID  StepId   StepName  Definition
```

**I can't use a GROUP BY clause:(**

Hopefully someone will get it right!

Comment: Why can't you use `group by`?  `window functions` that use `over` aren't supported in `mysql`.  Possibly with `user-defined variables` or with subqueries and `limit`, but again, why?

Comment: Better question is "Why can't you use group by? " than OP question

Comment: Because it's one of the constraint I have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why you cannot use `group by`, but here's one another option using a `correlated subquery`:

```
select ps.projectid, s.stepid, s.stepname, s.definition
from projectsteps ps 
  join step s on ps.stepid = s.stepid
where ps.projectid in (1,2,3)
  and s.stepid = (select stepid
                  from projectsteps ps2 
                  where ps.projectid = ps2.projectid
                  order by ps2.stepid desc
                  limit 1)
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56db30/1)